# Disable message 'Do you REALLY want to quit X11?'

Tags: macos, xorg, xquartz

I am on OS X 10.11.2, running [this version of X11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv7wE.png). When I quit X11, I get the dialog window 'Do you really want to quit x11?', of which I would like to get rid.

None of the answers that I found online worked (like [this one](https://www.macworld.com/article/1133068/x11quitwarn.html)) for me. In fact, I tried both

```
defaults write com.apple.x11 no_quit_alert true
```

and

```
defaults write org.x.x11 no_quit_alert true
```

from command line, but I still get that annoying window. Do you know why those solutions do not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me..

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 no_quit_alert true
```

Comment: Seems like it does not work in `BigSur`